# How do I write a mod_rewrite so that it doesn't affect a subdomain that is in a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have a site where the frontend is on the main domain and the backend is on a subdomain whose document root is a subfolder of the main domain's document root.

I have added this:

```
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

to the `.htaccess` file for the main domain because it was giving a 404 error for refreshes and direct access. The problem is that adding that config results in a 500 error on my backend. How can I solve this?

Comment: (I assume those backticks are just an error in your formatting?) What requests are you making to the subdomain? You shouldn't necessarily need to do anything, depending on the requests being made. You need to check your server's error log for details of the 500 error.

Comment: @MrWhite the backticks are an error I made will adding the code to the question. The log file strangely doesn't show the error. All I know is if I comment out that code in the .htaccess file then everything works on the subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't necessarily need to do anything with regards to the subdomain, depending on the type of requests you are making (which you've not stated).

However, you can disable mod_rewrite for the subdomain by creating an additional `.htaccess` file in the root of the subdomain (ie. in the subfolder off the main domain's document root) and place the following:

```
# /subfolder/.htaccess (subdomain)
RewriteEngine Off
```

`.htaccess` files are inherited along the filesystem path, so the `.htaccess` file in the root of the main domain will certainly be processed when accessing the subdomain, except that the *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) should already exclude any requests for actual files/directories.

Comment: This is an interesting way of looking at it. I hadn't looked at it from this perspective because I was too fixated on where I felt the breakdown was happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I only needed to add one line to exclude the affected subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\. [NC]
```

That did the trick.

Comment: That is one way to do it. Adding another `.htaccess` file in the root of the subdomain with `RewriteEngine Off` is another (and separates the configs). (Although, there is still the niggly question of why you needed to do this in the first place?)

Comment: Strictly speaking you should anchor the regex to avoid matching too much. And if there is a www sub-subdomain (as there often is with cPanel) then include this as well (or redirect it to canonicalise the request). eg. `!^(www\.)?example\.`.

Comment: @MrWhite regarding why I needed to do it, my front end is in Vue.js and it wasn't reloading pages and wasn't allowing direct access to other pages. A key feature of the application required direct access and reloading to work so that config was to address that particular problem. The only thing is that it was then affecting the API as well.